# How NFT image assets are combined?

Tags: erc-721, nft, mainnet

How do NFT projects combine their assets with all possible combinations? e.g. Cryptokitties: you have like 10 skin colors, 10 eyes shape ...etc. to combine these assets, you get let's say 10000 combinations, each one is unique.

My question is, which software (if any) can I use to combine specific assets into all possible unique combinations? or do I have to create my own software for that?

Answer (score 0):

Cryptokitties - and quite probably other similar NFT projects - uses an offchain [genetic algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm)<sup>1</sup> to assemble the unique combinations.

There were various articles at the time that attempted to explain how such alogorithms (probably) worked, such as the one by Hackernoon ([here](https://hackernoon.com/hacking-the-cryptokitties-genome-1cb3e7dddab3)). (I won't speculate further here.)

<sup>1</sup> *In computer science and operations research, a genetic algorithm (GA) is a metaheuristic inspired by the process of natural selection that belongs to the larger class of evolutionary algorithms (EA).*

Answer (score 0):

this repo does exactly what you are looking for

https://github.com/HashLips/hashlips_art_engine

here's their official youtube channel

https://www.youtube.com/@HashLipsNFT

this is a handy updated tutorial that uses the hashlips repo (but in spanish)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HK7CtS4hrmA&t=10s